# Is it possible to find the startTime and finishTime of each block of time in a mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a mysql table with three columns

```
Index, startTime, finishTime
1, 00:30:00, 01:45:30 
21, 01:45:30, 02:45:30 
36, 02:45:30, 02:55:00 
47, 02:55:00, 02:55:30 
58, 03:30:00, 03:45:30 
61, 03:45:30, 04:45:30 
99, 06:30:00, 06:45:30 
18978, 06:45:30, 06:45:40 
18978, 06:45:40, 06:55:40 
28888, 07:30:00, 09:45:30
```

Is it possible to find the startTime and finishTime of each block of time without a gap in a stored procedure?

ie: outputting the min startTime and the max endTime of each time block

```
00:30:00, 02:55:30
03:30:00, 04:45:30 
06:30:00, 06:55:40 
07:30:00, 09:45:30
```

Comment: Show us your current stored procedure.

Comment: What do you mean 'block of time'?